# Cmd to check pids used by particular cpu's

Tags: process, opensuse, cpu, top

In our environment we have applications running in servers with 0-3( total 4 cpu's). While seeing 'top' command and choosing 1 option, able to see 4 cpu's ( example: a server has 4 cpu's). In this server out of 4 cpu's how to find out the pids with respect to cpu0,cpu1,cpu2,cpu3. Since top commamd sometimes give 100% in any one of the cpu, what would happen in that case?

Comment: The Scheduler distributes the processes between the cpus. So the only way to "see" on process on a certain cpu is to use the tool "taskset". If you specify a single cpu for the process, it will only run on this cpu.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks. Is there anyother way to check. I am new to linux.

Comment: Processes can move off of CPUs or between CPUs  many times per second. Do you want to see what's running on each CPU every time there's a change, or just once every second or so?

Comment: Every second or period of 2 minutes

Comment: Well, as mitran said: the processes may move between the cpus several times a second. So checking every fee seconds will have no use. What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Hi, my requirement is during month end SAP application systems cpu reached nearly 100% and it vl be between 90-97%. Memory resource is normal only cpus usage is high. In order to determine which pid is using high cpu  would help us better.

Comment: what about interactively using "top" ?